# Draw Buttons in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want to draw buttons above a button onClick.
For Example If i have a share button and on click i want to draw two buttons Facebook and Twitter to share on one of them.
How can i draw the two buttons in code ?

Comment: for sharing, you should use this: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom dialog, it is more simple!
On click the Dialog will popup having Facebook button and twitter button.

Comment: Here is an example of a custom dialog in android http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/